# Name of method which includes Taylor linearization inside fixed point iteration

Tags: numerical-methods, taylor-expansion, nonlinear-optimization

I read paper about [Horn-Schunck multiscale method for computing optical flow](http://www.ipol.im/pub/art/2013/20/)

Core part of this algorithm is minimizing some functional. One part of functional contains nonlinear term inside L2 norm. Author uses Taylor expansion  to obtain linear approximation of term
\begin{equation}
    I(x+h^{n+1}(x)) = I(x+h^n(x)) + \nabla I(x + h^n(x))(h^{n+1}(x) - h^n(x))\\    
\end{equation}
Then author takes first derivative of functional and obtains $h^{n+1}$ by solving linear equality. 
Then old $h^n$ are replaced by $h^{n+1}$ and we repeat calculation until convergence.

So my question is what name of this method?

PS Sorry for my poor English and math skills

Comment: Seems to be very similar to gradient descent, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent

Comment: @Evgeny Thank you for answer but i am not sure that this algorithm is Gradient descent. In this method at every step we linearize non-linear term then minimizing L2 norm of these functional and than compute new approximation of non-linear functional and repeat process. In Gradient descent we just "walking" in direction of antigradient